# dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-bin_2.4.16-4+deb.sury.org~precise+4_i386.deb

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, php-5.3

I'm getting this error while updating my php version.

```
PHP  5.3.10
OS   Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS
```

while running command **`sudo apt-get install php5`**, get following error:

```
Unpacking apache2-bin (from .../apache2-bin_2.4.16-4+deb.sury.org~precise+4_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-bin_2.4.16-4+deb.sury.org~precise+4_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man8/apache2.8.gz', which is also in package apache2.2-common 2.2.22-1ubuntu1
dpkg-deb (subprocess): subprocess data was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-bin_2.4.16-4+deb.sury.org~precise+4_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I had tried following commands, but problem is still exists.

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

please suggest solutions for this, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem when upgrade PHP, you can try this

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-bin_2.4.16-4+deb.sury.org~precise+4_i386.deb
```

and then install php5 by

```
sudo apt-get -f install php5
```

This will upgrade apache2, enjoy it.